# How can I apply friction to a circular SKPhysicsBody

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am trying to understand friction, or some other aspect of physics, in SpriteKit. I created a circle that rotates. I placed a square on top of the rotating circle. I expected the square to rotate along with the circle and fall off, but the square does not move. I set `physicsBody.friction = 1.0` in an attempt to make the surfaces sticky but it does not help. What changes to physics do I need to make so that the square is affected by the circle's rotation?

I created a self-contained example using a Playground. To test:

1. Download attached bluecircle.png and place it on your desktop (or wherever)
2. Copy code below into your Playground
3. Change NSImage path to wherever you saved bluecircle.png

Code:

```
import Cocoa
import SpriteKit
import XCPlayground

let screenWidth = 1400.0
let screenHeight = 1000.0
let xOffset = 300.0

let smallsquareSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
let bluesquareSize = CGSize(width: 400 , height: 400)
// the img is a blue circle w/ radius of 200 located on my desktop
let img = NSImage(byReferencingFile: "/Users/CHANGETHIS/Desktop/bluecircle.png")

class PlayScene: SKScene {

    let redsquare = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: smallsquareSize)
    let greensquare = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.greenColor(), size: smallsquareSize)
    let bluesquare = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blueColor(), size: bluesquareSize)
    let bluecircle = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(image: img))

    var lastTime = NSTimeInterval(0)


    init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
    }


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView!) {

        backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()

        // RED SQUARE
        redsquare.position = CGPoint(x: screenWidth/2 - xOffset, y: screenHeight - 100)
        redsquare.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: smallsquareSize)
        redsquare.physicsBody.friction = 1.0
        addChild(redsquare)

        // BLUE SQUARE
        bluesquare.position = CGPoint(x: screenWidth / 2 - xOffset, y: screenHeight / 2)
        bluesquare.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bluesquareSize)
        bluesquare.physicsBody.dynamic = false
        bluesquare.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false
        bluesquare.physicsBody.friction = 1.0
        addChild(bluesquare)


        // GREEN SQUARE
        greensquare.position = CGPoint(x: screenWidth/2 + xOffset, y: screenHeight - 100)
        greensquare.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: smallsquareSize)
        greensquare.physicsBody.friction = 1.0
        addChild(greensquare)

        // BLUE CIRCLE
        bluecircle.position = CGPoint(x: screenWidth / 2 + xOffset, y: screenHeight / 2)
        bluecircle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 200)
        bluecircle.physicsBody.dynamic = false
        bluecircle.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false
        bluecircle.physicsBody.friction = 1.0
        addChild(bluecircle)

    }

    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        let delta = currentTime - lastTime
        lastTime = currentTime

        bluesquare.zRotation += delta
        bluecircle.zRotation += delta

    }
}

var view = SKView(frame:NSRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight))
var playScene = PlayScene(size: CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight))

view.presentScene(playScene)
view.showsFPS = true
view.showsDrawCount = true
view.showsNodeCount = true
XCPShowView("View", view)
```

`

[image: bluecircle.png]
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer  to your question are Joints . Creating a fixed joint between your nodes I believe will solve your problem .

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsJoint_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: The first obvious question, is is your physics simulation running at all. Meaning, if the circle moves to the left, does the square fall to the ground?

Comment: @CHBuckingham The physics simulation appears correct to me. The large blue square and small red square on the left test rotation and gravity. As the blue square rotates the red square is moved and falls.

Comment: I suspect that friction is only imparted by physicsBodies set to be dynamic. What happens when the circle is a dynamic physics object? You could also increase the density of the green square, just to test.

Comment: mihnea2kx, Joints are a good thought. After testing a fixed joint and a sliding joint I can tell that they do not create the effect I want. As the name implies, a joint is creating a connection between two physics bodies. A fixed joint makes the green square rotate in conjunction with the blue ball, but the square never falls off the screen. The green square effectively orbits the blue circle.

Comment: @CHBuckingham I made the blue circle dynamic and increased density to 1000. I also made the green square more dense. Neither scenario changed the behavior. The green square just sits perfectly atop the blue circle unaffected by the circle's rotation.

Comment: Then I'm guessing it's because you are actually rotating the circle in code and not imparting forces on it. I think I remember being frustrated by that distinction early on as well. Which would mean you'd use applyTorque: or applyForce:atPoint: to the circle. Or I could be completely leading you down a rabbit hole. :-D

Comment: In the touchesBegan method put an if statement checking if the circle body has rotation forces and then apply those forces or similar forces that create the effect  you want  to the other contact body and end those in the touchesEnded method . Might work