# Unexpected friction behaviour between two circular SKPhysicsBody objects in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am just getting to grips with the basics of SpriteKit (mainly as a learning exercise, but this might also become a game I release), and I am having issues trying to get the nodes involved to react to friction in the way I'd expect. This is similar to a previous question which is (so far) unsolved: [How can I apply friction to a circular SKPhysicsBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246984/how-can-i-apply-friction-to-a-circular-skphysicsbody)

**My current setup is as shown here:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r91X.png

*(Please ignore the pokeball image as a sprite, I'll obviously change this before I release anything)*

When I rotate right (***or clockwise as shown in step 1 of the image***), the ball behaves as I'd expect, i.e. it will roll down the top edge of the blue rectangle and then around the edge of the red circle until it falls off. (I've set up the red circle to be the parent node of the blue rectangle, so the rotation is applied to both objects simultaneously).

Where things come unstuck is the situation where you've used the blue rectangle to nudged the ball to the crest (top) of the red circle then stop rotating clockwise. At this point the ball will slowly start accelerating clockwise along the edge of the red circle.

My expectation here is that if you immediately start rotating left (***anti-clockwise, as shown in step 2***) the fact that there is (*or should be at least*) some friction between the ball and the red circle, would mean some amount of force is imparted on the ball to counteract its acceleration clockwise along the top edge of the red circle. This would allow you to mitigate the ball's acceleration, keeping it in contact with the red circle as you rotate the entire thing around.

The reason I want it to behave in this way is that I plan to add obstacles around the inside edge of the larger black circle which would result in a game over condition, and the winning condition would be a target zone on the opposite side of the blue rectangle from where the ball starts. Without friction interactions as I expect, the game would become impossible as you wouldn't be able to keep the ball in contact with the red circle as you rotate the puzzle scene.

N.B: Before you all suggest, I have tried setting the friction properties of all of the nodes' physicsBody properties to 1.0, which I believe is the max value, and this does not change the behaviour at all. Also the ball sprite is configured to allow rotation, which is also obviously needed I think.

Comment: Post your code. I have a hunch that you are modifying the rotation property or use a rotate SKAction. Instead you should use applyAngularImpulse on the physics body/bodies involved to rotate them. Otherwise the bodies won't have angular momentum which will affect friction (ie no friction as the inner red circle is not having angular momentum, ie it's as if it doesn't rotate from the perspective of the physics engine).

Comment: or `applyTorque` or set the `angularVelocity`. The latter is measured in radians per second.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D you're right, I was using an SKAction to rotate the red circle... I tried using `applyAngularImpulse` on the corresponding `SKPhysicsBody` but it didn't seem to do anything... Obviously the red circle is set to `dynamic = NO;` since I don't want it reacting to gravity, but will that also prevent impulses being imparted on to it?

Comment: Yup, it has to be dynamic. To disable gravity: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/affectedByGravity

Comment: cheers - that's helped with the friction behaviour... Now I'm running in to a "stuttering" effect in the rotation whilst the ball is in contact with the blue paddle as the whole thing is rotating. I'm guessing it's due to some force the ball is imparting on the paddle/red circle object (fixed together with an SKPhysicsJointFixed) - what's puzzling is I'm setting `angularVelocity` directly to a fixed value during a button press, so I wouldn't expect to see a variance in the rotational speed. I've also tried setting `usesPreciseCollisionDetection` to `YES` on each body, but that doesn't fix it.

Comment: My bad... I'd been overriding the `friction` on all the bodies involved (including the ball!) to be 1.0... hence the stuttering! All working now - cheers again guys :)